# How to load gridster with Chart.js dynamically on clicking a button?

Tags: angular, chart.js, angular-gridster2

I want to make a dynamic dashboard to display information with the ability to select a charts to represent it.

In my project, I connected the `angular-gridster2` package to work with a dynamic grid  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-gridster2.

I use the `Chart.js` library to work with charts.

For dynamic insertion of modules, I use `ndc-dynamic` package  https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-dynamic-component

The initial loading of the graphs is correct, but when I try to click the button to add another block with the corresponding chart, the block in the grid is added, and the chart is rendered not in the new added block, but in the same one where such a chart is already located.
I cannot understand why this is happening.

I presented all the code with working components in `stackblitz`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-axd7cw?file=src/app/components/chart-bar/chart-bar.component.html

Can anyone help me?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jazpvl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fchart-bar%2Fchart-bar.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fcomponents%2Fchart-bar%2Fchart-bar.component.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `id` inside your component. And while creating a chart you're referring to the `id` selector. So aparantly it is re-rendering 1st component that matches the `id` selector.

You have to generate a new `id` on each component generation and render that way.

**HTML**

```
<div class="chart">
  <canvas [attr.id]="id"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  const chartContext = Chart.getChart(this.id.toString());
  if (chartContext !== undefined) {
    chartContext.destroy();
  }

  this.loadLineChart();
}
loadLineChart() {
    this.myChart = new Chart(this.id.toString(), {
      type: 'line',
      ....
    });
}
```

[**Forked Stackbliz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bysb8t)

> **Note**:- Since we are generating an id from the component dynamically, we had move the graph plotting code from `ngOnInit` to `ngAfterViewInit` (to make sure `id` generated and updated on UI before query) lifecycle hook.

Comment: How, with this approach, when clicking on the "add graph" button, make a request to the server and display the graph with other data? I have both graphs with the same data displayed, although the data is different when requested in the cycle.

Comment: @Alex sorry to respond you late, is it possible for you to provide a stackblitz of problem statement?